# Assign variable content to object property name

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, javascript-objects

I want to create a json object in node.js that looks like this;

```
{ WantThisName: { property_length: 8 } }
```

Here is my code;

```
var property_name = "WantThisName"
var length = 8;

var Obj_bin;
Obj_bin= {property_name: {property_length:length} };
console.log (Obj_bin);
```

The console output is;

```
{ property_name: { property_length: 8 } }
```

The problem lies with `property_name` not getting the contents of the variable `property_name`.

Comment: Being discussed on meta [Is a question a duplicate when it has the same answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318996) (cc @thefourtheye)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use computed (dynamic) property names:

```
> foo = "foozz"
'foozz'
> {[foo]: 42}
{ foozz: 42 }
```

They're part of the Enhanced Object Literals of es2015 (https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#enhanced-object-literals).

For your example:

```
> var property_name = "WantThisName";
var property_name = "WantThisName";
undefined
> var length = 8;
undefined
> {[property_name]: { property_length: length}}
{ WantThisName: { property_length: 8 } }
>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Obj_bin = {};
Obj_bin[property_name] = { property_length: 8 };
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. I get error message `Obj_bin[property_name] = { property_length: 8 };
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'WantThisName' of undefined`

Comment: It works now! Sorry, my points are too low to give you an upvote.

Comment: @LitAiy no worries, glad to help